# Google Event Tracking Using jquery multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics

Complete novice and surprised to get this far, using google and youtube.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        jQuery('.apply_now_green, .apply_now_red, .feat_lender img, .feat_lender h3').click(function() {
            var label = jQuery(this).parents('.col-md-3').find('h3').text();
            ga('send', 'event', 'apply now button', 'click', label);

        });
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        jQuery('.more_details').click(function() {
            var label = jQuery(this).parents('.col-md-3').find('h3').text();
            ga('send', 'event', 'more details', 'click', label);

        });
    };
</script>
```

How can I merge the two, in the current format it wont work on analytics for tracking the two different events.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and what isn't working?

Comment: tracking event clicks on analytics,

we have apply buttons - which seems to work fine in terms of tracking,
and also a details button which takes users to a page with more information, we want to be able to track both.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [HTML5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to save your Analytics category/other data on the element itself.

In jquery you can do something like this:

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  var gaCategory = $(this).data('category');
  var gaLabel = $(this).data('label');
  
  alert('Category: ' + gaCategory + ', Label: ' + gaLabel);
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable" data-category="category1" data-label="label1"></div>
<div class="clickable" data-category="category2" data-label="label2"></div>
<div class="clickable" data-category="category3" data-label="label3"></div>
<div class="clickable" data-category="category4" data-label="label4"></div>
```